# How to get options from XSD for element\attribute using their xpath from xml file?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I have XML that is verified by xsd. 
To control user input in UI i need to know type, pattern, maxlength for elements and attributes.
So I need to get minOccures, type, pattern from xsd for some elements or attributes from my XML by their Xpath f.ex. 
How to get it?

Here similar question [Given an XML file and associated XSD, I'd like to find the XSD for elements in that XML instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280282)

Comment: For Xerces, use [PSVI](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html#faq-5). For .NET, use [XmlNode.SchemaInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.schemainfo(v=vs.110).aspx). Both cases, make sure you validate first. If the XML does not validate, you should not expect the PSVI information.

Answer (score 0):

It rather depends on the technology you are using. If you are using Saxon (it has to be Saxon-EE for schema-awareness), then after schema validation, you can call the extension function `saxon:type($node)` on any validated element or attribute node, and this will return information about the type that it was validated against. You can access properties of this type using function call syntax, for example `saxon:type($node)("name")` gives you the name of the type. Similarly `saxon:type($node)("facets")` will give you all the facets of the type, and if you want to find the value of the pattern facet you could use `saxon:type($node)("facets")[.("class")="pattern"]("value")`.

Of course this is all particular to Saxon, and if you are using a different schema-aware XPath processor you'll have to check to see if it offers similar capabilities. It might well involve writing your own extension functions.